# Avoid inserting duplicates in sql table through Entity Framework with multiple workers

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a SQL table called Domain which contains the following columns:

[image: SQL Table]

I have multiple agents (workers) inserting rows into the database at the same time and I want to avoid inserting duplicate domains. The Id is the primary key and I not willing to change it.

Meanwhile Im checking first if the domain exist by this:

```
public async Task<List<DomainApiModel>> GetListOfExistingDomainsAsync(List<string> domains)
{
    using (eTrafficBacklinks_V2Entities EMME_Context = new eTrafficBacklinks_V2Entities())
    {
        var rec = await EMME_Context.Domains.Where(p => domains.Contains(p.DomainName)).ToListAsync();
        return rec.Select(p => new DomainApiModel(p)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then I filter the ones already existent and, finally, I insert the non existing by the following code:

```
public int Create(List<DomainApiModel> domainApiList, out List<DomainApiModel> domainApiListWithId, int chunkSizeLimit = 500)
{
    using (eTrafficBacklinks_V2Entities EMME_Context = new eTrafficBacklinks_V2Entities())
    {
        EMME_Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        EMME_Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

        int totalChanges = 0;

        var listOfLists = domainApiList.ChunkSplit(chunkSizeLimit).ToList();
        var listOfDomainData = new List<Domain>();
        foreach (var list in listOfLists)
        {
            foreach (var apiModel in list)
            {
                var objectData = apiModel.GetDataObject();
                EMME_Context.Domains.Add(objectData);
                listOfDomainData.Add(objectData);
            }

            totalChanges += EMME_Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        domainApiListWithId = listOfDomainData.Select(d => new DomainApiModel(d)).ToList();

        return totalChanges;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the meantime between checking if the domain exists and creating, another agent can insert the same domain and I am having duplicates in my table.

Anyone has any light of how to solve this problem?

Obs: I have the same problem with a table called page with the "url column" which is nvarchar950 type, so creating just a unique index is not a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional Index on all columns that need to be unique. Columns that are to big to be indexed can be indexed by a computed hash.

Here a concept for creating many entities and how to track the exceptions:

```
class MyService
{

    public async Task<OperationResult<string, SomeEntity>> CreateManyAsync( IList<string> data, int chunkSize )
    {
        var succeded = new List<SomeEntity>( );
        var failed = new List<FailedOperation<string>>( );

        foreach ( var chunk in data.Select( ( dataItem, index ) => new { data = dataItem, chunk = index % chunkSize } ).GroupBy( c => c.chunk, c => c.data ) )
        {
            try
            {
                succeded.AddRange( await InternalCreateManyAsync( chunk ) );
                continue;
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                // we just eat this exception
            }

            foreach ( var singleItem in chunk )
            {
                try
                {
                    succeded.Add( await InternalCreateSingleAsync( singleItem ) );
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    failed.Add( new FailedOperation<string>( singleItem, ex ) );
                }
            }
        }

        return new OperationResult<string, SomeEntity> {
            Succeded = succeded,
            Failed = failed,
        };
    }

    private async Task<IList<SomeEntity>> InternalCreateManyAsync( IEnumerable<string> data )
    {
        var result = new List<SomeEntity>( );

        using ( var db = new MyCOntext( ) )
        {
            foreach ( var item in data )
            {
                result.Add( AddSingleToContext( item, db ) );
            }
            await db.SaveChangesAsync( );
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<SomeEntity> InternalCreateSingleAsync( string data )
    {
        using ( var db = new MyContext( ) )
        {
            var e = AddSingleToContext( data, db );
            await db.SaveChangesAsync( );
            return e;
        }
    }

    private SomeEntity AddSingleToContext( string data, MyContext context )
    {
        var entity = new SomeEntity { Data = data, };
        context.SomeEntities.Add( entity );
        return entity;
    }

}
```

some utility classes

```
class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

class FailedOperation<T>
{
    public FailedOperation( T data, Exception error )
    {
        Data = data;
        Error = error;
    }

    public T Data { get; }
    public Exception Error { get; }
}

class OperationResult<TSource, TResult>
{
    public IList<TResult> Succeded { get; set; }
    public IList<FailedOperation<TSource>> Failed { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be easily solved adding a unique index to the table. Any attempt to add a duplicate value will throw an exception.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_DOMAIN_NAME
ON DOMAIN (DOMAIN_NAME)
```

Beware than it will require you to add each new value independently or the whole transaction will fail, even for those non duplicated values.

```
foreach (var list in listOfLists)
        {
            foreach (var apiModel in list)
            {
                var objectData = apiModel.GetDataObject();
                EMME_Context.Domains.Add(objectData);
                listOfDomainData.Add(objectData);
                try{
                  totalChanges += EMME_Context.SaveChanges();
                }
                 catch(SqlException se){
                    if(se.Number != 2601) // Unique key violation
                    {
                       // Handle other errors
                    }
                 }
            }
}
```

Comment: How I deal with the exception? If I am adding multiple domains before calling SaveChanges(), the exception will cancel all the domains that I added before.

Comment: @juanora "adding like this will kill the performance" You can't have it all ;-)

Comment: Also this wont solve if my column is a long string like nvarchar900 which is not possible to create a index for this

Comment: Moreover, I can have it all by you method using AddOrUpdate()

Comment: @juanora In case you column is longer than nvarchar(max) you could have a calculated column containing text's hash in you ddbb. Then set the unique index on this column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132781/discussion-between-juanora-and-oscar).